# bootstrap list with images doesnt display inline

Tags: html, css, list

it may seem a bit stupid and overly simple, but i'm new to coding and can't get it to display properly (i'm using bootstrap). Result i want to get is `FLAG languagename    FLAG languagename`

HTML:

```
<div class="">
<ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">
  <li><a href="#"><div class="flag flag-lt"></div>Lietuvių</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><div class="flag flag-ru"></div>Rusų</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.flag {
  width: 16px;
  height: 11px;
  background:url(http://oi60.tinypic.com/2q2iuj6.jpg) no-repeat
}

.flag.flag-lt {background-position: -16px 0}
.flag.flag-ru {background-position: 0 -11px}
```

i made a [js filldle](http://jsfiddle.net/aivaraspauga/c8zHF/1/) with external resourses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this work you need to add one of these to your flag css block:

```
display: inline-block;
```

or

```
float: left;
```

Comment: display: inline-block on the flag block worked :) thnx